# What is the best function to make user input safe for the database?

Tags: php, mysql, database

what is the best function to use in a php code, that makes the user input safe for the databse ?
I know about removing spaces before and after the string.
striping the slashes from the string.

and what else ?

and can we use this function in a login script ?
and is there any other security issues we have to worry about ?

and thank you very much :D

Comment: That depends on what database library you are using. Every library brings its own sanitation function. Removing slashes and spaces won't help

Comment: PDO is the real solution, since you write prepared statement preparing your database to a certain query. So that the database can itself understand what is an argument and what is part of the query string.

Answer (score 4):

[PDO::prepare()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php)

As for other possible vulnerabilities, there are lots; I suggest having a look at [19 Deadly Sins of Software Security](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0072260858) and something like a [PHP Security Checklist](http://www.sk89q.com/2010/04/printable-php-security-checklist/).

Comment: +1, I wish we could just drop the old mysql library completely :(

Answer (score 2):

Prepared statements with MySQLi functions. https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your database engine.

- For MySQL, use
  [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string)
- For SQLite, use [sqlite_escape_string](http://php.net/sqlite_escape_string)
- For PostgreSQL, use [pg_escape_string](http://php.net/sqlite_escape_string)
- For IBM DB2, use [db2_escape_string](http://php.net/db2_escape_string)
- And so on...

Comment: Or, even better, it *doesn't* depend on your database engine, and you use PDO for all of them, as in Marco's answer.